# How to savetxt with numpy different data formats?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to stack column wise a list A and array B as shown below:

**Input**

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C']

B = [[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
     [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
     [11 12 13 14 15 16]]
```

**Desired output in text format**

```
A   1   2   3   4   5    6
B   6   7   8   9   10   11
C   11  12  13  14  15   16
```

But when I use this code:

```
import numpy as np
A = ['A', 'B', 'C']
B = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]])
C = np.column_stack((A, B))
print (C)
```

I get this output:

```
[['A' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6']
 ['B' '6' '7' '8' '9' '1' '1']
 ['C' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1' '1']]
```

Why is it outputting only single digits?

And how to savetxt with numpy with mixed formats, for this I tried:

```
np.savetxt('test.txt', np.column_stack((A, B)),  fmt='%s %0.2f')
```

But this results in an error. How to get the desired output in text file?

Comment: try this one `np.savetxt('/tmp/test.txt', np.column_stack((A, B)),  fmt='%3s')`

Comment: First, the column_stack at my end working properly, last row numbers have two digits but all elements are character now. If you really want to save this with desired format of your own, I suggest try to write code segment with csv writer. That would be better and faster.

Comment: @vrajs5, what's your dtype of `C` there? Mine is `dtype('<U1')` with numpy v1.8.1, so it's wrong.

Comment: @wim The last digits are missing when I use the given command.

Comment: `A=np.array(['A','B','C'],dtype='a2')` gets around this issue on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with `np.__version__` being 1.8.1. I think it's a buggy implementation of `np.column_stack`, or `np.concatenate` to be precise.

You can convert `B` to string type using `astype` first:

```
In [49]: C = np.column_stack((A, B.astype('S')))

In [50]: C
Out[50]: 
array([['A', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
       ['B', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'],
       ['C', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16']], 
      dtype='|S24')

In [5]: np.concatenate((A, B[2]))
Out[5]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

### EDIT:

After updating my `numpy` package, that issue is gone:

```
In [3]: np.__version__
Out[3]: '1.9.2'

In [4]: C = np.column_stack((A, B))
   ...: print (C)
[['A' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6']
 ['B' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11']
 ['C' '11' '12' '13' '14' '15' '16']]

In [9]: np.concatenate((A, B[2]))
Out[9]: 
array(['A', 'B', 'C', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'], 
      dtype='|S11')
```

Comment: @wim, aha.. have you tried? `np.column_stack((A, B))` won't work properly.

Comment: oh, maybe its a bug.  I'm on 1.9.1 and I don't see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of `concatenate` function that `np.column_stack` use it for concatenate the arrays :

source of [`np.column_stack`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L278) :

```
arrays = []
for v in tup:
    arr = array(v, copy=False, subok=True)
    if arr.ndim < 2:
        arr = array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
    arrays.append(arr)
return _nx.concatenate(arrays, 1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> np.concatenate((A,B[2]))
array(['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> A = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']
>>> np.concatenate((A,B[2]))
array(['AA', 'BB', 'CC', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```